# I hosted a server in eclipse by tomcat but cant access localhost:8080 or my jsp page from browser

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, localhost

So I am a complete newbie in using tomcat and servers and jsp. Just trying to open a webapp made by someone else but I cant set up the server... below are what i've done to try to solve the problem:

1. I can open `localhost:8080` if I run the server from *Configure Tomcat* (not in eclipse)
2. I've checked `server.xml` file and the localhost is indeed 8080
3. I've set the `server location` to `use tomcat installation` in eclipse
   [image]
4. I can run the server in eclipse, it appears fine but I just cannot open the localhost:8080 page from browser. - the error says something like `Chrome failed to access localhost:8080` and i back to eclipse page it would show that the server is "[starting, synchronized]".
5. BUT If i try to open my web app from browser like `http://localhost:8080/my-app-name` it would show the error `the connection to localhost is stopped` - and when I back to eclipse the server was "[stopped, synchronized]".
6. I cannot access either `localhost:8080` or `120.0.0.1`.

and below is the log files appear in my console when i am starting up the server within eclipse:(ignore the chinese, they re irrelevant)

```
4月 21, 2014 1:24:08 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
資訊: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_13/bin/../jre/bin/server;c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_13/bin/../jre/bin;c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_13/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32\wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Program Files\SciTools/bin/pc-win64;C:\Users\kimlu\Downloads\eclipse;;.
4月 21, 2014 1:24:08 上午 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:a_small_book_db' did not find a matching property.
4月 21, 2014 1:24:09 上午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
資訊: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
4月 21, 2014 1:24:09 上午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
資訊: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
4月 21, 2014 1:24:09 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
資訊: Initialization processed in 2558 ms
4月 21, 2014 1:24:09 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
資訊: Starting service Catalina
4月 21, 2014 1:24:09 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
資訊: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
4月 21, 2014 1:24:10 上午 org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
資訊: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [101] milliseconds.
4月 21, 2014 1:24:10 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
資訊: Deploying web application directory docs
4月 21, 2014 1:24:11 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
資訊: Deploying web application directory examples
4月 21, 2014 1:24:11 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
資訊: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
4月 21, 2014 1:24:12 上午 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
資訊: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
4月 21, 2014 1:24:12 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
資訊: Deploying web application directory host-manager
4月 21, 2014 1:24:12 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
資訊: Deploying web application directory manager
4月 21, 2014 1:24:12 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
資訊: Deploying web application directory ROOT
4月 21, 2014 1:24:12 上午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
資訊: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
4月 21, 2014 1:24:12 上午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
資訊: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
4月 21, 2014 1:24:12 上午 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
資訊: Server startup in 3174 ms
```

My browser is not in english so i cannot tell what exactly the error message was! But it should be very close to what i stated above. Please help! thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granted I'm swinging in the dark here, but you try localhost:8005 to see if the admin port works yet? or just 8080?

Are there logfiles that you can view? Looks like you get the server up and listening, when something tries to connect that's when the port closing?

First step that I would try is change the port to something else other than the one for web traffic see if that resolved it. Best of luck though.

Comment: wow thanks! 127.0.0.1:8080/my-app-name actually works :) but it says `The requested resource (/a-small-book-db) is not available.` I wonder if its i typed the wrong app name? Edit: I failed to access to localhost before but atfer i tried `127.0.0.1` it works. and then I can access `localhost:8080` from browser again. I don't know what's wrong before...but thank you very much!

Comment: So that's going to be a problem with the database not being created yet it looks like. Glad the loopback was the issue :) that was an easy fix. At moment its looking for a database entry that's not been setup yet. Have to run for work mandated lunch be back 30 mins :)

Comment: :) thanks! have a nice lunch:) One more question: I'd have to create the database now... I need to create some SQL queries for it(I guess?) , i wonder if i can do everything in eclipse?(means i dont have to use mySQL or anything else?)(this is such a dump question, sorry! I'm just completely unfamiliar with it)

Comment: @Sue no problem at all. If your unfamiliar with SQL here's a crash course. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-database.html this should help you out there as that's a whole different conversation.

Shown below you can create databases in Eclipse but you'll need an additional plugin.
https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-EclipseDbWebapps/index.html

Comment: Thanks! :) You've really helped a lot :-)

Comment: Always a pleasure. I'm stuck at work and that is fun to me. I enjoy programming, client/server relationships, you name it. And if I don't know it becomes personal :) Good luck and I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: :) haha! Sometimes I just stuck in a problem for too long and it is really painful to deal with...:( all these weird errors are driving me mad lol